# How do I loop through a string and convert to lowercase?

Tags: c++, string

I know there were a couple of other questions on this from a while back, but I looked over those and still couldn't figure it out. I'm trying to take user input in the form of a string, then loop through that string converting all of the uppercase to lowercase so that I can display it all in lowercase.
Where am I going wrong?

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter Text: ";
    string Text;
    getline(cin, Text);
    for(int i=0; i<Text.length(); i++)
    {
        if(islower(Text[i]) == false)
        {
            tolower(Text[i]);
            i++;
        }
        Text[i] = Text[i];
    }
    cout << "Your text is: ";
    cout << Text;
    cout << "\n";
}
```

I'm very new to C++ and I'd be lying if I said I had much of an idea even where I was going wrong. Line 11, where the *for* loop is says that it's trying to compare two different signs, but I don't know what that means or if that's the source of my problem. Line 15 where the *tolower()* is says that it's 'ignoring return value of function declared with pure attribute' but I still don't know what that means either.
Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A few points**:

- `tolower` returns the lowercase character if it exists (`'A'` becomes
  `'a'`, `'a'` is unchanged, `'9'` is unchanged, etc.)
- The line `Text[i] = Text[i];` does not do anything, you want `Text[i]
  = tolower(Text[i]);`
- There is no need to check if each character is lowercase, `tolower`
  will handle that for you

**Simplified**:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter Text: ";
    string Text; 
    getline(cin, Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < Text.length(); i++)
        Text[i] = tolower(Text[i]);
    cout << "Your text is: ";
    cout << Text;
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the std library algorithm function **transform** to simplify and to make the code easier to read for you and others.

```
#include <iostream> //for cout and getline
#include <algorithm> //for transform
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter Text: ";
    string Text;
    getline(cin, Text);
    //This will iterate over each character [Text.begin()-Text.end()] and then
    //replace it by a call to tolower with itself as a parameter
    transform(Text.begin(), Text.end(), Text.begin(), ::tolower);
    cout << "Your text is: ";
    cout << Text;
    cout << "\n";
}
```

**EDIT:**

As Remy pointed out to correct way of implenting this is by using a proxy lambda since

> the behavior of std::tolower is undefined if the argument's value is
>   neither representable as unsigned char nor equal to EOF.

```
transform(Text.begin(), Text.end(), Text.begin(), 
          [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });
```

Comment: This is not the *correct* way to use `tolower()` as a predicate for `std::transform()`. See [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) for an explanation and example of the *correct* way.

Comment: Also this should be applied to asimes answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at the ascii tables to see the codes for upper case and lower case characters.
http://www.asciitable.com/

```
bool islower(char in)
{
   return !(char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z'); //we do this so if its a not an alphabet character we don't get false positives
}


char tolower(char in)
{
   return char-'A' + 'a'; //essentially get its distance from the start of the
                          //alphabet and add this distance to the lowercase (only works on uppercase)
}
```

Its all just about working with the ascii values to get what you want since all characters are essentially integers.